# You must be vs you must

Tags: grammar

Which is the correct sentence:

1. You must like Nirvana ! / You must like it !
2. You must be like Nirvana ! / You must be like it !

Intended to guess whether They like Nirvana or not.

Comment: What did you find when you looked up "to be" in the dictionary?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your first example is correct.
Your second example means "You must be *similar/comparable to* Nirvana".

Comment: Please resist the temptation to answer questions so obviously inappropriate on ELU, a site aimed at linguists.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new here. Should I delete my answer?

Comment: Better to read the advice at the Help Center and look at some other questions to get a feel for acceptable levels. There is a sister site for more basic questions, ELL.